# JupyterNotebook with Args Parser

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-model', type=str, default='linear_model')
parser.add_argument('-featuredim', type=int, default=20)
parser.add_argument('-inputfeatures', type=str, default='/Users/myname/Downloads/face-rating-master/data/features_ALL.txt')
parser.add_argument('-labels', type=str, default='/Users/myname/Downloads/face-rating-master/data/ratings.txt')
```

The above code can be run successfully. The following line

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

gives this error:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-model MODEL] [-featuredim FEATUREDIM]
                             [-inputfeatures INPUTFEATURES] [-labels LABELS]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: argument -featuredim: invalid int value: '/Users/myname/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-7d72fc3c-2c11-47e4-87f3-3587b2461a52.json'
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

Code from https://github.com/avisingh599/face-rating

Comment: In the notebook you don't have a command line do you?  where do you expect it to get the arguments to parse from?

Comment: Truely. Is there any work around in notebook ?

Comment: You can try args = parser.parse_args(args=[])

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
    args = parser.parse_args() #call from command line
except:
    args = parser.parse_args(args=[]) #call from notebook
```

Comment: please add context so we can learn. Keep in mind that its an older question so version number are important to state in your answer due to evolution of code. EoR. Welcome and enjoy SO :-)

Comment: This worked for me. Seems command line args aren't passed in when executed in a notebook (_duh_!)

Answer (score 0):

The *featuredim* argument expects an integer (i.e., `type=int`) but you've passed in a string that indicates the path to a json file.

You could get this script to work by re-engineering its logic a bit so that it would read in a JSON and then extract the integer from a key value (similar to how many scripts will read in .ini configuration files), but within the context of what you're doing that's overkill (and really wouldn't help much with your dilemma, since you want to use Jupyter).  For reference, the file that you're passing into the script doesn't give you direct access to the variables defined in your notebook, and just stores information used by the application (such as the IP address that the notebook is running on and the TCP port number that it is using).  To illustrate, this is what a similar JSON file on my laptop looks like:

```
09/28 18:26:53 [jsp2205@kaheta: ~/Library/Jupyter/runtime]
$ less kernel-40dad791-ffa1-4687-bcd1-3ec831884c83.json
{
  "stdin_port": 60476,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "control_port": 60477,
  "hb_port": 60478,
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "key": "b52ef99c-0a1a70b17b600daea5263a29",
  "kernel_name": "",
  "shell_port": 60474,
  "transport": "tcp",
  "iopub_port": 60475
}
```

Your best bet is to take the code from trainModel.py, remove ArgumentParser, and replace any references to the arguments with hardcoded variables.  Then add each of the lines in the modified code to your Jupyter notebook and modify the hardcoded variables manually within the notebook.

For other scripts using ArgumentParser, you might want to see if they pass the arguments extracted using `parse_args()` into a function, and then use an import statement similar to the following to import that function directly into your notebook.  So something like the following:

```
cd [directory containing script]
from [script name minus the .py extension] import [function name]
```